# Finding a function $f$ such that $f(3n)=1$, $f(3n+1)=5/3$, $f(3n+2)=8/3$, where $n$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Determine a function $f(x)$ such that :
>
> - $f(3n)=1$
> - $f(3n+1)=5/3$
> - $f(3n+2)=8/3$
>
> where $n$ is an integer

How can you determine it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: $f\colon \Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Q$ is the function $1,5/3,8/3,\ldots 1,5/3,8/3,\ldots$. What is the domain of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, topicstarter wants some closed form description of his function like 
$$f(k)=\frac{9}{2}(1*(k+1-3[\frac{k+1}{3}])(k+2-3[\frac{k+2}{3}])+\frac{5}{3}*(k-3[\frac{k}{3}])(k+1-3[\frac{k+1}{3}])+\frac{8}{3}*(k+2-3[\frac{k+2}{3}])(k-3[\frac{k}{3}]).$$

Comment: Yeah, in my case, that's the kind of equation I'm looking for. However, how did you even come up with that equation, though?

Comment: Here, I'm looking for some inticator function which is nonzero on one of cases and is zero on other cases. After that I summarize all theese functions with corresponding coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&& \text{if $x=3n$ for some integer $n$}\\
\frac53&& \text{if $x=3n+1$ for some integer $n$}\\
\frac83&& \text{if $x=3n+2$ for some integer $n$}\\
0&&\text{any other point in the domain of }f
\end{cases}$$
A closed form description of this function is 
$$f(x)=\mathbf1[3\Bbb Z]+\dfrac53\times\mathbf1[3\mathbb Z+1]+\dfrac83\times\mathbf1[3\Bbb Z+2]$$
where $\mathbf1[A]$ is the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: In fact, for "any other point in the domain", $f$ can attain any arbitrarily chosen value.

Comment: Yea, @AryanSonwatikar, but why complicate things!

Comment: Or better, define it as $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking of an equation that works for any x. Like f(x)=cos(x)^2+cos(x)+3.
It sure is simple that way.

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci, what I wrote works for any $x$, that is a discontinuous function, though.

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci, added the closed form.

Comment: @Martund And adding the closed form using indicator functions is trivial, right?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar, yes, that is :P

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to interpret the question and find an answer.
The trigonometric sum function
$$ f(x) := \frac{16}9 - \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\sin(2\pi x/3)
 - \frac79\cos(2\pi x/3) $$ satisfies the conditions you specified.
 For example,
$$ f(3n) = \frac{16}9 - \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\sin(2\pi n) - \frac79\cos(2\pi n) 
  = \frac{16}9 - 0 - \frac79 = 1. $$
The three constants were determined by solving three linear equations.

Comment: I think your equation is wrong because when x=3n, f(x)=(16-3*sqrt(3))/9 which is not equal to 1.

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci Oops! A silly copy error. Will fix! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Wait i did a mistake i switched the cosine and the sine. You're right !